# Eclipse open file using drag and drop

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I have installed `Aptana Studio 3.04` (a custom build of Eclipse for web development).

Now i just want to open a file via drag and drop, but i can't - no area in the window accepts dropping a python file. Is it possible?

`File -> Open file...` - works perfectly. I use `Kubuntu 10.04`.

[image: Eclipse window]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to have a project open to be able to open a file via dragging.